# Stand-alone Exchange 2007 conversion from existing SBS 2003 environment?

Tags: exchange-2007, exchange-2003, windows-sbs-2003

We have an existing SBS 2003 sever setup running Exchange, AD, Internal DNS, etc.

Has anyone ever kept all of the SBS 2003 functions running while splitting out Exchange *AND* doing so to an upgraded Exchange environment (Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2007)?

Hope my question makes sense...

Answer (score 1):

I actually just completed a migration like this for a customer of mine. They had a SBS2k3 box that they wanted to move away from, but wanted to do it in stages. The process is much less painful than migrating anything with AD, since SBS doesn't need to be the primary mail server, just the primary DC.

Comment: RANT - There are no "primary DC" computers in Active Directory. The SBS computer needs to be a global catalog server, and has to hold the five flexible single-master roles (including one called "PDC Emulator"), but it's not a "primary" copy of Active Directory. Other DC's are equal copies of the database. /RANT  Having said that, migrating Exchange off of the SBS computer ought to be pretty straightforward. I'd mock it up in a lab once before doing it "live", but it ought to go pretty easily.